# How to find this series coefficients?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to find the following series coefficients:
\begin{equation}\sum_2^\infty B_{n}[\sin(nx)-n\cos(nx)]=\sin(x)+\frac{x^2}{\pi}-x\end{equation}

Interval is $[0,\pi]$.

I tried:
\begin{equation}B_{n}=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi} \left(\sin(nx)-n\cos(nx)\right)\left(\sin(x)+\frac{x^2}{\pi}-x\right)dx\end{equation}

So I found:

\begin{equation}B_{n}=\frac{2}{\pi^2}\left[\frac{2+n^2(-2+\pi)+(n^2(2+\pi)-2)(-1)^n}{n^5-n^3}\right]\end{equation}

The problem is the denominator of $B_{n}$ which must be $n^7-n^3$ instead of
$n^5-n^3$.

The solution in my tutor's PDF is:
\begin{equation}B_{n}=\frac{2}{\pi^2}\left[\frac{2+n^2(-2+\pi)+(n^2(2+\pi)-2)(-1)^n}{n^7-n^3}\right]\end{equation}

Where is the problem?

Comment: $B_n$ is defined by $B_n=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi (\sin(x)+\frac{x^2}{\pi}-x)\sin nx\rm dx = \frac{1}{2n\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi (\sin(x)+\frac{x^2}{\pi}-x)\cos nx\rm dx$.

Comment: That is, if the interval on which the equality holds is $[-\pi,\pi]$. I didn't verified. But your way of computing $B_n$ is strange.

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS The interval is $[0,\pi]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the basis functions $u_n = \sin(nx) - n \cos(nx)$ are orthogonal on $[0,\pi]$, with $\int_0^\pi u_n^2(x)\; dx = \pi (n^2+1)/2$.  Thus the coefficients for a function $f(x)$ that has such a series should be 
$$ b_n = \frac{2}{\pi(n^2+1)} \int_0^\pi u_n(x) f(x)\; dx $$
In this case, if $n \ne 1$, 
$$ \eqalign{B_n &= \frac{2}{n^2+1} \int_0^\pi (\sin(nx)-n\cos(nx))\left(\sin(x)+\frac{x^2}{\pi}-x\right)\; dx \cr
&= {\frac {2\,\pi\, \left( -1 \right) ^{n}{n}^{2}+2\,\pi\,{n}^{2}+4\,{n}^
{2} \left( -1 \right) ^{n}-4\,{n}^{2}-4\, \left( -1 \right) ^{n}+4}{{n
}^{3}\pi^2\, \left( {n}^{4}-1 \right) }}
} $$
while
$$B_1 = \frac{\pi^2-8}{2\pi^2}$$

Comment: Thank you! What about $B_{0}$ is that $\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi} (sin(x)+\frac{x^2}{\pi}-x)dx$ or $\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi} (sin(x)+\frac{x^2}{\pi}-x)dx$?

Comment: Is there a $B_0$?  For $n=0$, $\sin(nx) - n \cos(nx) = 0$.

Comment: Hm: these $f_n$ are eigenfunctions for $f''= \lambda f$ with boundary conditions $f(0) = -f'(0)$, $f(\pi) = -f'(\pi)$. Besides $f_n$ for positive integers $n$, the other eigenfunction  is $\exp(-x)$.  So that's what will give you another term in the expansion..